# Interpreting a Table for Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, bayes-rule

[image: Consider the probkem of binary classification using Naive Bayes Classifier. You are given two dimensional features and categorical conditiobal distributions in the tables below.]The question and related table is given in the picture. I applied bayes rule as:
$\cfrac{P(X_1=-1,X_2=1|C_1)}{P(X_1=-1,X_2=1)} = \cfrac{P(X_1=-1|C_1)P(X_2=1|C1)P(C_1)}{P(X_1=-1|C_1)P(X_2=1|C1)P(C_1) + P(X_1=-1|C2)P(X_2=1|C2)P(C_2)}$

From the table, I think:

$P(X_1=-1|C_1)=0.2$

$P(X_2=1|C1)=0.1$

$P(X_1=-1|C2)=0.3$

$P(X_2=1|C2)=0.6$

I couldn't make anything about $P(C_1)$ and $P(C_2)$. May you please help me?
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Edit:Picture is added!

Comment: You didn't attach any picture.

Comment: @Tim, picture has been added. Sorry for that mistake.

Comment: @kursat Forgive me if I misunderstand, but the "...two classes are equally likely..." should imply that $P(C_1)=P(C_2)=0.5$. Also, I think there is a typo on the LHS part of the equation where you apply Bayes' rule (missing $P(C_1)$)